# How to add Azure API Soup wsdl in Java

Tags: java, azure

Could there be a WSDL API Definition in Azure Cognitive Services other than the two definitions (Swagger and WADL).
I am currently using the API, but failed to get its WSDL Definitions in order to consume it.

*** Help ***

Comment: What API of Azure Congnitive Services are you using? Almost all apis of Azure Congnitive Services are based on REST/JSON style in the request/response body for calling. Please move to [here](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/documentation) to know the details about congnitive service usage, and improve the description of your issue about what you did.

Comment: Thanx for the link @Peter